# Python Convert HTML into JSON using Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

These are the rules

1. The HTML tags will start with any of the following `<p>`, `<ol>` or `<ul>`
2. The content of the HTML when any of step 1 tags is found will contain only the following tags: `<em>`, `<strong>` or `<span style="text-decoration:underline">`
3. Map step two tags into the following: `<strong>` will be this item `{"bold":True}` in a JSON, `<em>` will `{"italics":True}` and `<span style="text-decoration:underline">` will be `{"decoration":"underline"}`
4. Any text found would be `{"text": "this is the text"}` in the JSON

Let’s say l have the HTML below: By using this:

```
soup = Soup("THIS IS THE WHOLE HTML", "html.parser")
allTags = [tag for tag in soup.find_all(recursive=False)]
```

Which produces this Array:

```
[
    <p>The name is not mine it is for the people<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>stephen</strong></em></span><em><strong> how can</strong>name </em><strong>good</strong> <em>his name <span style="text-decoration: underline;">moneuet</span>please </em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>forever</strong></span><em>tomorrow<strong>USA</strong></em></p>,
    <p>2</p>,
    <p><strong>moment</strong><em>Africa</em> <em>China</em> <span style="text-decoration: underline;">home</span> <em>thomas</em> <strong>nothing</strong></p>,
    <ol><li>first item</li><li><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>second item</strong></span></em></li></ol>
]
```

**By Applying the rules above, this will be the result:**

*First Array element would be processed into this JSON:*

```
{
    "text": [
        "The name is not mine it is for the people",
        {"text": "stephen", "decoration": "underline", "bold": True, "italics": True}, 
        {"text": "how can", "bold": True, "italics": True},
        {"text": "name", "italics": True},
        {"text": "good", "bold": True},
        {"text": "his name", "italics": True},
        {"text": "moneuet", "decoration": "underline"},
        {"text": "please ", "italics": True},
        {"text": "forever", "decoration": "underline", "bold":True},
        {"text": "tomorrow", "italics": True},
        {"text": "USA", "bold": True, "italics": True}
    ]
}
```

*Second Array element would be processed into this JSON:*

```
{"text": ["2"] }
```

*Third Array element would be processed into this JSON:*

```
{
    "text": [
        {"text": "moment", "bold": True},
        {"text": "Africa", "italics": True},
        {"text": "China", "italics": True},
        {"text": "home", "decoration": "underline"},
        {"text": "thomas", "italics": True},
        {"text": "nothing", "bold": True}
    ]
}
```

*The fourth Array element would be processed into this JSON:*

```
{
    "ol": [
        "first item", 
        {"text": "second item", "decoration": "underline", "italics": True, "bold": True}
    ]
}
```

**This is my attempt so, l am able to drill down. But how to process arrayOfTextAndStyles array is the issue**

```
soup = Soup("THIS IS THE WHOLE HTML", "html.parser")
allTags = [tag for tag in soup.find_all(recursive=False)]
for foundTag in allTags:
   foundTagStyles = [tag for tag in foundTag.find_all(recursive=True)]
      if len(foundTagStyles ) > 0:
         if str(foundTag.name) == "p":
              arrayOfTextAndStyles = [{"tag": tag.name, "text": 
                  foundTag.find_all(text=True, recursive=False) }] +  
                    [{"tag":tag.name, "text": foundTag.find_all(text=True, 
                    recursive=False) } for tag in foundTag.find_all()]

         elif  str(foundTag.name) == "ol":

         elif  str(foundTag .name) == "ul":
```

Comment: You need to come up with a more consistent output format; why is the second paragraph not resulting in a list, while the others all do? Why doesn't the third paragraph have an initial text element before all the nested dictionaries?

Comment: Alternatively, why not wrap *all* text in a dictionary? So for the first example, the first element would be `{"text": "The name is not mine it is for the people"}`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  have edited output 2

Comment: Where did `can` go in your first example? How should `<em><strong> how can</strong>name </em>` be handled, really? It's a nested structure with text at two levels.

Comment: There is also a space between '<strong>good</strong>' and `<em>his name ...`, followed by more nesting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited the question to include "can" in the output. I omitted it

Comment: @MartijnPieters you can ignore the space.

Comment: Then your text can't be reconstructed. You *have* to track spaces. Use a nested structure that is consistent. My answer below produces such a structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a function to parse each element, not use one huge loop. Select on `p` and `ol` tags, and raise an exception in your parsing to flag anything that doesn't match your specific rules:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString

def parse(elem):
    if elem.name == 'ol':
        result = []
        for li in elem.find_all('li'):
            if len(li) > 1:
                result.append([parse_text(sub) for sub in li])
            else:
                result.append(parse_text(next(iter(li))))
        return {'ol': result}
    return {'text': [parse_text(sub) for sub in elem]}

def parse_text(elem):
    if isinstance(elem, NavigableString):
        return {'text': elem}

    result = {}
    if elem.name == 'em':
        result['italics'] = True
    elif elem.name == 'strong':
        result['bold'] = True
    elif elem.name == 'span':
        try:
            # rudimentary parse into a dictionary
            styles = dict(
                s.replace(' ', '').split(':') 
                for s in elem.get('style', '').split(';')
                if s.strip()
            )
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Invalid structure')
        if 'underline' not in styles.get('text-decoration', ''):
            raise ValueError('Invalid structure')
        result['decoration'] = 'underline'
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid structure')

    if len(elem) > 1:
        result['text'] = [parse_text(sub) for sub in elem]
    else:
        result.update(parse_text(next(iter(elem))))
    return result
```

You then parse your document:

```
for candidate in soup.select('ol,p'):
    try:
        result = parse(candidate)
    except ValueError:
        # invalid structure, ignore
        continue
    print(result)
```

Using `pprint`, this results in:

```
{'text': [{'text': 'The name is not mine it is for the people'},
          {'bold': True,
           'decoration': 'underline',
           'italics': True,
           'text': 'stephen'},
          {'italics': True,
           'text': [{'bold': True, 'text': ' how can'}, {'text': 'name '}]},
          {'bold': True, 'text': 'good'},
          {'text': ' '},
          {'italics': True,
           'text': [{'text': 'his name '},
                    {'decoration': 'underline', 'text': 'moneuet'},
                    {'text': 'please '}]},
          {'bold': True, 'decoration': 'underline', 'text': 'forever'},
          {'italics': True,
           'text': [{'text': 'tomorrow'}, {'bold': True, 'text': 'USA'}]}]}
{'text': [{'text': '2'}]}
{'text': [{'bold': True, 'text': 'moment'},
          {'italics': True, 'text': 'Africa'},
          {'text': ' '},
          {'italics': True, 'text': 'China'},
          {'text': ' '},
          {'decoration': 'underline', 'text': 'home'},
          {'text': ' '},
          {'italics': True, 'text': 'thomas'},
          {'text': ' '},
          {'bold': True, 'text': 'nothing'}]}
{'ol': [{'text': 'first item'},
        {'bold': True,
         'decoration': 'underline',
         'italics': True,
         'text': 'second item'}]}
```

Note that the text nodes are now **nested**; this lets you consistently re-create the same structure, with correct whitespace and nested text decorations.

The structure is also reasonably consistent; a `'text'` key will either point at a single string, *or* a list of dictionaries. Such a list will never mix types. You could improve on this still; have `'text'` *only* point to a string, and use a different key to signify nested data, such as `contains` or `nested` or similar, then use just one or the other. All that'd require is changing the `'text'` keys in `len(elem) > 1` case and in the `parse()` function.

Comment: I am testing, and l will get back soon. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it possible to covert the entire result into valid json array, such as json.dumps(result) for the final result. The result looks very promising, however, the final output is not in a json format i.e. result

Comment: @ErnestAppiah: I've updated the answer to fix a small bug in handling nested elements with multiple children.

Comment: @ErnestAppiah: the final output is trivial to produce. Instead of `print(result)` in the last snippet (where I loop over `soup.select('ol,p')`), append the result to a list. Then use `json.dumps(list_produced)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. You are awesome. How can l give you 500 stars. Thanks so much. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Will definately get you one of your wish list https://www.amazon.co.uk/registry/wishlist/1E5V9AJISGDO5