# How to get right JSON responce from POST request from PYTHON script

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, post, python-requests

### Task is to get JSON responce from POST request from particular website.

Everything works fine in browser as follows. You may simulate the case yourself tryin to start enter text into Start Location field.

webaddress to check: https://www.hapag-lloyd.com/en/online-business/schedules/interactive-schedule.html

[Chrome Dev Tool Screen 1 - Request URL and Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkSjG.jpg)

[Chrome Dev Tool Screen 2 - POST data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee4rT.jpg)

### JSON RESPONCE (it must be like this)

```
{"rows":[{"LOCATION_COUNTRYABBREV":"GE","LOCATION_BUSINESSPOSTALCODE":"","LOCATION_BUSINESSLOCATIONNAME":"BATUMI","LOCATION_BUSINESSLOCODE":"GEBUS","STANDARDLOCATION_BUSINESSLOCODE":"GEBUS","LOCATION_PORTTYPE":"S","DISPLAYNAME":""}]}
```

My code as follows:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.hapag-lloyd.com/en/online-business/schedules/interactive-schedule.html?_sschedules_interactive=_raction&action=getTypeAheadService'

POST_QUERY = 'batumi'

params = {
    'query': POST_QUERY,
    'reportname': 'FRTA0101',
    'callConfiguration': "[resultLines=10,readDef1=location_businessLocationName STARTSWITH,readDef2=location_businessLocode STARTSWITH,readClause1=location_businessLocode<>'' AND location_portType='S' AND stdSubLocation_string10='STD',readClause2=location_businessLocode<>'' AND location_portType<>'S' AND stdSubLocation_string10='STD',readClause3=location_businessLocode<>'' AND location_portType='S' AND stdSubLocation_string10='SUB',readClause4=location_businessLocode<>'' AND stdSubLocation_string10='SUB',readClause5=location_businessLocode='' AND stdSubLocation_string10='SUB',sortDef1=location_businessLocationName ASC,resultAttr1=location_businessLocationName,resultAttr2=location_businessLocode,resultAttr3=location_businessPostalCode,resultAttr4=standardLocation_businessLocode,resultAttr5=location_countryAbbrev,resultAttr6=location_portType]"
}
headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-EN,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Host': 'www.hapag-lloyd.com',
    'Origin': 'https://www.hapag-lloyd.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    # 'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.hapag-lloyd.com/en/online-business/schedules/interactive-schedule.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
}

print('Testing location: ', POST_QUERY)
var_cities = requests.post(url,data=params,headers=headers)
print(var_cities.content) #it does print some %$#%$
```

[Python Print Content Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPFII.jpg)

My question is "How to get right JSON responce from POST request from PYTHON script"?

Comment: Almost solved. This particular site requires different approach since the webpage is being rendered by JS. Will try Selenium WebDriver or QT5.

Answer (score 0):

I think using BeautifulSoup is a better option.
Try this

[Python Convert HTML into JSON using Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483313/python-convert-html-into-json-using-soup)

Comment: There is no useful responce to parse. Server returns dummy HTML instead of JSON with useful data.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(var_cities.text)
```

This returns the html as string. Is this what you expected to get as a response? And to convert this into json, look at the answer above...

Comment: var_cities.json() doesn't work since there is no JSON content in responce.  This returns an exception "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: yes, but I dont see your wished response in the html. So I am not sure if the problem is only the formatting?

Comment: This is what i answered to the first guy: "Server returns dummy HTML instead of JSON with useful data."